# Baseline profile, Android TV, StartupBenchmarks

Tags: android, android-tv, baseline-profile, macrobenchmark

I am trying to implement a Baseline Profile for Android TV. To be honest, I haven't found any official documentation on this. Generation baseline-prof.txt worked well. But the StartupBenchmarks tests don't work. It shows:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2018)
at androidx.benchmark.ShellImpl.createShellScript(Shell.kt:719)
at androidx.benchmark.Shell.executeScriptCaptureStdoutStderr(Shell.kt:406)
at androidx.benchmark.Shell.executeScriptCaptureStdoutStderr$default(Shell.kt:400)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkScope.dropKernelPageCache(MacrobenchmarkScope.kt:391)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:446)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:422)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmark$measurements$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:251)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmark$measurements$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:241)
at androidx.benchmark.perfetto.PerfettoTraceProcessor$Companion.runServer(PerfettoTraceProcessor.kt:105)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmark(Macrobenchmark.kt:241)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode(Macrobenchmark.kt:422)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule.measureRepeated(MacrobenchmarkRule.kt:107)
at ru.haier.evo.baselineprofile.StartupBenchmarks.benchmark(StartupBenchmarks.kt:31)
at ru.haier.evo.baselineprofile.StartupBenchmarks.startupCompilationBaselineProfiles(StartupBenchmarks.kt:28)
```

If anyone has encountered this problem, please give me some advice

[image]